# Joomla 3.4.4. tmp directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I have problem with installing any extensions in Joomla! 3.4.4.

When I try to install any i have error

> An error has occurred.
>
> ```
> -1 Copy file failed
> ```

I set all CHMOD for 777 (for tests) in configuration.php there is correct path to tmp directory. One thing that is strange is info in joomla backend:

> The PHP temporary folder is not set. The PHP temporary folder is the
>   folder that PHP uses to store an uploaded file before Joomla can
>   access this file. Whilst the folder not being set isn't always a
>   problem, if you are having issues with manifest files not being
>   detected or uploaded files not being detected, setting this in your
>   php.ini file might fix the issue.

I don't have access to php.ini so i can't use upload_tmp_dir . When i try make my own php.ini file and then make rule in .htaccess nothing happens. Maybe someone had the same problem?

Comment: Try creating a .user.ini file (instead of php.ini). Some hosts do not allow php.ini, but they do allow .user.ini. Also, have you tried seeing the output of the phpinfo() function (which reveals all the information about PHP's setup)?

Comment: `The PHP temporary folder is not set.` >> This is done in the Joomla Global Configuration (admin backend)

Comment: @Lodder tmp folder is set correctly, itoctopus I've tried with user.ini and nothing happened ...

Answer (score 0):

Set the directory to 755 firstly. No need for 777.

Make sure the directory is linked via the home i.e.

/home/your_user_account/public_html/tmp

And also then check your hosting package has not run out of diskspace.

These are the common problems.

Comment: XWS it must be something else...

Funny is that I've install from internet for example "module manager" but i can't install "admin tools"

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting environment or a custom VPS / LAMP? IF you try installing Admin Tools via URL does that work?

Comment: problem solved. I've update joomla from 3.4.3 to 3.4.4. manually, and then set permissions once again and it started to work. Thank You all for attention!